# query to fetch First Login and Last Logout date time and Door Number for date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

There is Employee Table Containing Employee Login Details Like.

### Employee table

| Employee ID | Name | LoginDateTime | LogoutDateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1/1/21 8:15 | 1/1/21 10:55 |
| 1 | A | 1/1/21 11:30 | 1/1/21 13:15 |
| 1 | A | 1/1/21 15:20 | 1/1/21 17:15 |
| 1 | A | 1/1/21 18:15 | 1/1/21 22:15 |
| 2 | B | 1/1/21 9:15 | 1/1/21 10:55 |
| 2 | B | 1/1/21 11:30 | 1/1/21 13:15 |
| 2 | B | 1/1/21 15:20 | 1/1/21 16:15 |
| 3 | C | 1/1/21 8:15 | 1/1/21 11:15 |
| 3 | C | 1/1/21 12:15 | 1/1/21 14:25 |
| 3 | C | 1/1/21 15:35 | 1/1/21 23:56 |
| 1 | A | 2/1/21 8:15 | 2/1/21 10:55 |
| 1 | A | 2/1/21 11:30 | 2/1/21 13:15 |
| 1 | A | 2/1/21 15:20 | 2/1/21 17:15 |
| 1 | A | 2/1/21 18:15 | 2/1/21 22:15 |
| 2 | B | 2/1/21 9:15 | 2/1/21 10:55 |
| 2 | B | 2/1/21 11:30 | 2/1/21 13:15 |
| 2 | B | 2/1/21 15:20 | 2/1/21 16:15 |
| 3 | C | 2/1/21 8:15 | 2/1/21 11:15 |
| 3 | C | 2/1/21 12:15 | 2/1/21 14:25 |
| 3 | C | 2/1/21 15:35 | 2/1/21 23:56 |

Now my Query is how to fetch employee details for each date like.

### Expected result

| Employee ID | Name | First Login | First Login Door No | Last Logout | Last Logout Door No |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1/1/21 8:15 AM | D1 | 1/1/2021 22:15 | D1 |
| 2 | B | 1/1/21 9:15 AM | D2 | 1/1/2021 16:15 | D1 |
| 3 | C | 1/1/21 8:15 AM | D2 | 1/1/2021 23:56 | D3 |
| 1 | A | 2/1/21 8:15 AM | D1 | 2/1/2021 22:15 | D1 |
| 2 | B | 2/1/21 9:15 AM | D2 | 2/1/2021 16:15 | D1 |
| 3 | C | 2/1/21 8:15 AM | D2 | 2/1/2021 23:56 | D3 |

Comment: Don't use links. Especially not to images. Post your complete question and data here, so we can read it. Please see [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: And don't tag different DBMS (MySQL, SQL-Server). Only post the DBMS that you are actually using.

Comment: At last show us what you have tried and explain where you got stuck, so we know what exactly you want us to tell you.

Comment: henceforth,will take care about the same

Comment: Okay. So, what *is* your DBMS?

Comment: My DBMS is SQL-Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the first login and last logout per user. One way to achieve this is to aggregate once to get those two datetimes per employee and then join the rows:

```
select
  e.employee_id,
  e.log_name as name,
  f.login_datetime as first_login_datetime,
  f.door as first_login_door,
  l.logout_datetime as last_logout_datetime,
  l.door as last_logout_door
from
(
  select
    employee_id,
    max(name) as log_name,
    min(login_datetime) as min_login_datetime,
    max(logout_datetime) as max_logout_datetime
  from mytable
  group by employee_id
) e
join mytable f on f.employee_id = e.employee_id
              and f.login_datetime = e.min_login_datetime
join mytable l on l.employee_id = e.employee_id
              and l.logout_datetime = e.max_logout_datetime
order by e.employee_id;
```

As to the name in the table: It seems this column exists, because an employee's name can change and you want to log the name the employee had at the time of login/logout. I don't know whether you want one result row per employee or one per employee/name. I assumed the former and just display one of their names found in the table. This may or may not be what you want. If it isn't, it shouldn't be too difficult to adjust the query accordingly, though.

**UPDATE:** You want to restrict this to logins in a certain date range, say January 2012. And you don't want to see the first login and last logout per employee, but per employee and login date. This basically means we must change the subquery by adding a `WHERE` clause and extending the `GROUP BY`:

```
select
  e.employee_id,
  e.log_name as name,
  e.login_date,
  f.login_datetime as first_login_datetime,
  f.door as first_login_door,
  l.logout_datetime as last_logout_datetime,
  l.door as last_logout_door
from
(
  select
    employee_id,
    convert(date, login_datetime) as login_date,
    max(name) as log_name,
    min(login_datetime) as min_login_datetime,
    max(logout_datetime) as max_logout_datetime
  from mytable
  where login_datetime >= '20210101' and login_datetime < '20210201'
  group by employee_id, convert(date, login_datetime)
) e
join mytable f on f.employee_id = e.employee_id
              and f.login_datetime = e.min_login_datetime
join mytable l on l.employee_id = e.employee_id
              and l.logout_datetime = e.max_logout_datetime
order by e.login_date, e.employee_id;
```

Comment: its not work for me because there is multiple date login details in table and I just want to fetch min and max logout date time along with entry door no for a date range. Like Cast(LoginDateTime as date) Between '2021-01-01' and '2021-01-31'.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are saying. You want to limit this to logins in January 2021?  Do you want to limit the logouts, too? Can't you just add a `WHERE` clause then? It would have been good had you included an explanation in your request describing what exactly you want. BTW: I suppose that a users sessions cannot overlap (e.g. login to door 1, login to door 2, logout of door 1, logout of door 2)?

Comment: basically table contain login logout details of employees for each date and a employee can have multiple times login and logout in a day from different different door that why need to fetch data foreach employee their first login entry and door number and the last exit and door number for each date.

Comment: Okay, you don't want one result row per employee, but one result row per employee and date. Can it happen that a user logs in before midnight and logs out after midnight? If so, would you want to see that logout time with the login date although it's the day after?

Comment: yes, it is possible that user logout after midnight, so in this case we need actual logout date & time but login date must be in specified date range.

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer with a solution. You should have been able to do this yourself, actually. It is not that hard to find out how t get from a datetime to a date. And where to place the `WHERE` clause should be obvious. And if you don't want a result row per employee (GROUP BY <employee>), but per employee and date, you need of course GROUP BY <employee>, <date>. At last I have added the date to the `SELECT` list and the `ORDER BY` to get a readable result.

Answer (score -1):

What I did was calculate the minimum login time for each employee and the maximum logout time for each employee, and then join the tables to the employee code.

Then, to retrieve other table information, I join the shortest entry time to the main table and did the same for the longest logout time.

```
select 
   e1.EmployeeID, 
   e1.Name,t1.FirstLogin,
   e1.DoorNo as FirstLoginDoorNo
   ,t2.LastLogin,
   e2.DoorNo as LastLoginDoorNo
from
   (select
        EmployeeID,
        min(LoginDateTime) as FirstLogin
        from Employee
        group by EmployeeID) t1
   join 
   (select
        EmployeeID,
        max(LogoutDateTime) as LastLogin
        from Employee
        group by EmployeeID) t2

   on t1.EmployeeID = t2.EmployeeID 
   join 
   Employee e1
   on t1.EmployeeID = e1.EmployeeID and t1.FirstLogin = e1.LoginDateTime
   join 
   Employee e2
   on t2.EmployeeID = e2.EmployeeID and t2.LastLogin = e2.LogoutDateTime
```

Comment: You got confused somewhere. Your `ROW_NUMBER` expression numbers an employee's rows arbitrarily, so you stay with random rows. You probably do so assuming that all rows of an employee have the same selected data, but that isn't the case. For one the door number differs, and then, the `ORDER BY` in `MIN/MAX OVER` creates arbitrary minimum and maximum values for the rows, because you ask for the min/max up to that row thus.

Comment: I modified the code because I could not get DoorNo for every login and logout. But the first code worked with any kind of data!!

Comment: Sorry to say, this is still wrong. Do you know what `min(LoginDateTime) over(partition by EmployeeID order by EmployeeID)` does? (People say that `SELECT DISTINCT` is almost always a sign for a poorly written query. I think so, too. So, every time you use it, ask yourself, why you are forced to do so. Most often you have created an undesired intermediate result you must boil down to what you actually wanted. In your case you have used window functions were mere aggregation functions would be more appropriate. And you even used them wrong.)

Comment: So test the above code with different data and see if it produces the desired result or not and where is the wrong code?:)

Comment: Thanks Meysam for Reply, but issue not resolve

Comment: I think the output is wrong. Why is all EmployeeID = 1?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I would be happy if someone made a mistake somewhere and it would be a learning class for me

Comment: yes sorry for that, its by mistake, Employee Id is accordingly 1,2,3

Comment: @Book Store: I stand corrected. Your query works in spite of the nonsensical `ORDER BY` clauses, because the omitted windowing clause defaults to `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`. I thought it to be `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`. Nonetheless, they make no sense and just confuse the reader. And why use window functions at all, when you must use `DISTINCT` then to get down to a mere aggregation? Why not aggregate down to employee right away? That would make the query more readable and save the DBMS some work.

Comment: Oops, the last comment was meant for @Meysam Asadi of course. Sorry